# why ResNet50 include_top argument giving error?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Keras version - 2.2.4

Python - 3.6.6

issue:

```
from resnet50 import ResNet50
```

[image]
----> 6 model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, 
include_top=True,weights='imagenet')

TypeError: _obtain_input_shape() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_top'

is there a fix for this?

Comment: Please include a full working example, including all imports, and the full backtrace.

Comment: This is not a full working example, and its very bad practice to include code as images. Prefer text.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=True,weights='imagenet')
```

**With:**

```
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input,require_flatten=True,weights='imagenet')
```